# Select element in angular not updating modelValue on second selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

I've got a select element bound to a model in an angular view.  When filling out the form with the keyboard, I noticed that if you down arrow to the second option the value, the model still represents the first value.  This only happens when using the keyboard to fill out the form.

Set up is pretty simple, using angular 1.4.3:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', function() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.options = [{
    Id: 1,
    Value: 'A'
  }, {
    Id: 2,
    Value: 'B'
  }, {
    Id: 3,
    Value: 'C'
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
    <p>
      Model is not updated on second down button push. Repro:
      <ol>
        <li>Tab to select element</li>
        <li>Hit down and notice the optionId updated to 1</li>
        <li>Hit down again and notice that the displayed value changes to B, but optionId stays as 1</li>
        <li>Hit down again and notice that the displayed value changes to C, and optionId changes to 3</li>
        <li>Hit up and notice that displayed value changes to B, and optionId changes to 2</li>
      </ol>
      Why doesn't the optionId = 2 on the initial selection of B
    </p>
    <select id="mySelect" ng-options="item.Id as item.Value for item in ctrl.options" ng-model="ctrl.optionId" style="width:200px">
    </select>
    <div><strong>optionId: {{ctrl.optionId}}</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Why doesn't the model update on the second down arrow press?

**Update**
Here's a plunker that exhibits the behavior, http://plnkr.co/edit/Hiu67NTR3Gpk9jByZtQD?p=info

**2nd Update**
Here's a [modified plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GTqM1K4efjmWdOQGMGAH?p=preview) that implements the workaround Matt proposed.  This workaround causes the desired behavior in Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer

Comment: Up. Weird. Hope you solve this i'm curious as to whats going on. Suspecting it's a bug

Comment: Very weird indeed.  I've opened up an issue https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12562

Comment: What browser are you using? I see the issue in Chrome, but in IE11 (on Win7), all seems fine. I wonder if it is more a dropdown issue in the browser

Comment: It doesn't trigger the `onchange` event on the select. Like @MattTester I can only replicate in Chrome.

Comment: I was using Chrome.  Can't repro in IE.  Interestingly in Firefox 40.0.2, It doesn't appear the model is updated at all while using the keyboard.  I never see a value for the optionId

Comment: In the thread that @Matt mentioned, I guess FireFox is following the spec when it doesn't fire a change event on keyboards event for selects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your problem clones a pre-existing angular issue which has a work around available.

Feel free to browse [the issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9134) and trace the conversation and some of the duplicates.

The work around suggested for Chrome/Safari/Firefox looks like this:

```
directive('changeOnKeyup', function changeOnKeyupDirective() {
  return function changeOnKeyupPostLink(scope, elem) {
    elem.on('keyup', elem.triggerHandler.bind(elem, 'change'));
  };
});
```

Edit:

The OP's [issue](http://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12562) in the comments above was closed as a duplicate for this reason.

Comment: Alright that might work.  May need to include for firefox too, because the keyboard events don't cause change events in FF according to that thread.

Comment: @Dustin Hodges That solution works for me in FF as well using the plnkr mentioned in the issue. (http://plnkr.co/edit/PcD55HqECuJrSC9usUFv?p=preview)