# Angular ng-change directive does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using a nya-bs-select dropdown in which when i use ng-change,it does not populate the value ng-model.Instead it populate the last selected value in drop down.When i use ng-click, it works good.
Below is my html code

```
<ol id="singleSelection" class="nya-bs-select" ng-model="selectedFilterData" 
    ng-change="updateTableData(cellValues)">
    <li class="nya-bs-option" ng-repeat="i in cellValues" 
        data-value="{{i[filterColName[0]]}}">
        <a>{{i[filterColName[0]]}}</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

and ng-controller code is

```
$scope.updateTableData = function(currdata) {
  console.log("table data :"+$scope.selectedFilterData);
}
```

please advise

Comment: Are you using chrome?  Do you get different behavior in IE or firefox.  There's a question here that might apply, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953009/select-element-in-angular-not-updating-modelvalue-on-second-selection

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can't have `change` event on `ol` element, it should have `input` element to bind change event. You have `ol` so it won't work with it.

Comment: That is surprising since nya-bs-select dropdown comes with dropdown creation using ol element.Please advice if we can have a work around.